# Do you need to buy Visual Studio to develop/deploy an ASP.NET web application?

Tags: .net, asp.net

Since the [.NET Framework SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK) is free, is Visual Studio anything more than an IDE? If yes, do I need to buy Visual Studio to deploy my ASP.NET web application (written in C#)? I'm using MySQL for the database.

I'm a student that is going to graduate college soon, and I'm exploring technologies for a web application that I'm building for a startup.

Comment: As far as I'm aware of, all you need is IIS, which in turn requires you to have one of the beefed up versions of Windows (in other words, not "home" edition).

Comment: You do not need a 'beefed up version of Windows' to develop .Net applications. You can use IIS Express which is a lightweight, self-contained version of IIS optimized for developers. http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you don't need Visual Studio to build web applications - you can use the SDK directly if you wish.

However, Visual Studio also exists in free [Express editions](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express). These are stripped-down single-language/single-platform versions of Visual Studio (for example, there is no support for plugins), but otherwise completely usable for building your applications.

In your case, you can use [Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express) to work with ASP.NET applications.

Comment: Plus, as a student you probably qualify for Dreamspark (https://www.dreamspark.com/) which would provide a full copy of Visual Studio, Windows Server editions for IIS, and free training, too.

Comment: I actually do. But I'm not sure if sticking with MS technologies would turn out to be expensive later.

Comment: The express editions have a non-commercial licensing term that may bite you if you're not careful. I use it to compile the Windows Native version of one of my Java libraries, and the non-commercial restriction sticks out in the EULA like a sore thumb.  If my library weren't OSS I'd be worried about that term.

Comment: @CharlesChappell are you sure? My understanding is you're welcome to sell apps you built with VS Express.

Comment: @CharlesChappell: I just checked the C# and C++ Express EULAs, and there is no such clause in there. The oonly use of the word commercial is a bit about not being allowed to "use the software for commercial software hosting services", but that would be something along the lines of offering Visual Studio itself as a commercial service.

Comment: Here's a similar question about this term in the EULA.  It seems the meaning of this is open to a lot of interpretation.  IANAL, but it looks like a pretty solid "do not use it for commercial reasons" to me.  In any event, I'm not the only confused party. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/f280e5b7-f17a-4984-9b08-28c5449b6417

Comment: @CharlesChappell: Read the answer below that. The VS 2008 Express FAQ, which was the relevant one at the time of that post, explicitly stated that you're allowed to sell the stuff you make with it.

Comment: The linked FAQ is no longer accessible, but I did realize that was the implication.  The EULA terms were at best ambiguous about this point, which I do concede I was wrong about.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.asp.net/ is also a good landing point: there's a download icon with a "free" banner in the middle, at the top. These 'all-in-one' downloaders are excellent for getting you going easily with everything you need, all tied together nicely.

Good Luck!